The telebot library terminates the script with exit code 0xC0000135
I am writing a bot for Telegram using the telebot library (pyTelegramBotAPI).
Steps completed:

installed Python 3.
installed this library: pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
updated Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable

I have written the script and run it - it ends with the following message: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
This message is displayed even if the script is shortened to one line:
import telebot

What could be the cause of this error?
